# How to fix code in method CellFormatting in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have got `DataGridView` it is filled by from DataTable.

I format values of some cells using method `CellFormatting`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0)
            return;
        if (e.ColumnIndex < 0)
            return;

        // Pass

        string pass = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn52"].Value.ToString();
        e.Value = (pass == "1") ? "Повторно" : "Первый раз";

        // Status

        string status = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn58"].Value.ToString();

        if (status == "1")
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["edit"].Value = Properties.Resources.edit_disable;
        }
    }
}
```

This method returns me an error:
[image]

I think problem is in assignment of `e.Value.` It happens sometimes in `Cell Formatting`. And Value is overwritten.

Do you see any wrong code?

Comment: a) please post only real code; the above code seems to miss a curly and, I hope, the catch/finally clause. b) the error mentions an exe; does it happen in debug mode also? c) are you sure the Cell.Values can't be null? d) I'm not even sure that you are allowed to change the value in this event as it should trigger it again, which might lead to the loop the error mentions..

Comment: You're not just changing the formatting, though. You're changing the values of other cells in the row. I wouldn't be surprised if that's what's causing your infinite loop.

Comment: Then how to change value of concrete cell by name? in formatting?

Comment: This is full code. I posted all

Comment: I will be thankful for solution as answer for my case.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx)  : `ConvertEventArgs.Value` is where you can slip in a new value for the cell in question. But you should probably not set the DGV values as you do in the Cells["edit"] cell. The event is really only for formatting the cell it refers to! You could maybe hack by also returning if it is called for the edit column : `if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "edit") return;`

Comment: Do you mean to add just `if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "edit")` before assigment?

Comment: Either that or put it to the top along with the other two tests. The event is called so often it should only do what is really necessary, so restricting it to only the relevant columns is recommended..

Comment: The contents of the "See Details" section of that error-dialog might be helpful to see, too. :-)
And, have you tried setting a breakpoint early in this method and stepping through the code to see what's happening?